# Is it possible to use the postgresql array overlap operator (&&) with Dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

I have the following query that works in postgres:

```sql
SELECT name FROM people
WHERE ARRAY['john', 'sue'] && (name)
```

However when I try to replicate it through dapper, I get the following error:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: operator does not exist: record && text[]
```

The sql dapper is passing to `QueryAsync` is:

```sql
SELECT name FROM people
WHERE @name && (name)
```

Where @name is a `DynamicParameter` of type `string[]` containing "John" and "Sue"

I'm wondering if anyone has a solution to this or if it's just not possible, thanks.

I have also tried wrapping the parameter with `ARRAY[]`

```sql
WHERE ARRAY[@name] && (name)
```

This also doesn't work and results in error `Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: operator does not exist: record[] && text[]`

Comment: Check the error message, @name is casted as a record and not as an array

Comment: How are you passing through `@name` please show code. Sounds like Dapper is not passing through the parameter correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, it turns out this was due to another connection layer messing with the parameters. The original code works fine through dapper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).